# I am getting an error that "multiclass format is not supported"

Tags: pandas, roc

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, out_pred_prob)
# create plot
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC curve')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--', label='Random guess')
_ = plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
_ = plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
_ = plt.title('ROC Curve')
_ = plt.xlim([-0.02, 1])
_ = plt.ylim([0, 1.02])
_ = plt.legend(loc="lower right")
```

"multiclass format is not supported"

Comment: Could you show us the input data?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is a great resource on how to ask a good question and maybe elicit better answers!

Comment: out_pred_prob = gmodel.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
out_pred_prob

Comment: array([0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000, 4.82324017e-263, 0.00000000e+000,
       2.54835609e-244, 4.71099695e-274, 3.86153488e-203, 0.00000000e+000,
       2.35397798e-203, 0.00000000e+000, 0.00000000e+000])

Comment: Please post the complete error report starting with traceback. You can surround the report with 3` before and 3` after to properly format the output.

Comment: Please provide as an edit to your question a sample of the contents of  variables ```fpr```, and ```tpr```.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.